# Python package called SignalFx, how to get _logger to print to stdout

Tags: python, logging

There is a Python package for [SignalFx](https://www.signalfx.com/): [link to GitHub source](https://github.com/signalfx/signalfx-python)

In one of its files, it makes a `_logger` object that uses Python's `logging` library. The package has many `_logger.debug()` statements that make it useful in debugging connectivity problems.

The code instantiates the `_logger` as a global variable, like so:

`_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

[Source line in GitHub](https://github.com/signalfx/signalfx-python/blob/master/signalfx/ingest.py#L25)

I have searched for a while, and can't figure out how to view the `_logger.debug()`'s output.  How can I get the `_logger` to print to `stdout`?  Or, where can I view the log statements?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay to circle back on this one, I finally have an answer built up based on two questions:

1. The question here: [How to use logging.getLogger(__name__) in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50714316/11163122)
2. The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56840272/11163122

The first question was useful because I realized why the package used `getLogger(__name__)`.  It also made me realize I just needed to get access to the package's base logger, named `signalfx`.

The second answer was useful because I realized I could basically import the logger without needing to import `_logger` from SignalFx.

My final solution (in my code), was this:

```
sfx_logger = logging.getLogger("signalfx")
sfx_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sfx_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```

Now, the SignalFx logger prints to `stdout`, and I can see all the debug statements!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to configure logging in your application which uses SignalFx. For example, this might work in your main program script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging  # if not done already

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(name)s %(message)s')

    # and then the rest of your script's code
```

If that doesn't produce results, you probably need to give more information about how your code that uses SignalFx is organised.