# Python can you accidentally overwrite a logger by using getLogger with the same name?

Tags: python, logging

In my Python program, I import a module (let's say it's called `bananas`). The module gets a logger inside its `__init__.py` by doing this:
`_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.  Thus, the logger's name is `bananas`.

In my program (the one that imports the module `bananas`), I also have this line: `my_logger = logging.getLogger("bananas")`.

Does this:

- Overwrite `_logger` made in `bananas`?
- Fetch that logger, and thus `my_logger` now equals `_logger`?
- Something else entirely

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fetches the `bananas` logger, so that `my_logger` is the same object as `bananas._logger`.

Comment: Thank you @Vinay Sajip!