# Python difficulty understanding getLogger(__name__)

Tags: python, logging

Im quite confused on the logging docs' explanation of `getLogger(__name__)` as a best practice.

Gonna be explaining my entire thought process, feel free to leave a comment any time I make a mistake

The logging [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) says

> A good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level
> logger, in each module which uses logging, named as follows: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Say I have a project structure:

```
main_module.py
cookbook_example
---auxiliary_module.py
```

main_module.py

```py
import logging
from cookbook_example import auxiliary_module
# Creates a new logger instance
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Create file handler that logs debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log', mode='w')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Create a formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.info('Creating instance of auxiliary_module.Auxiliary')
a = auxiliary_module.Auxiliary()
logger.info('Calling auxiliary_module.do_something')
a.do_something()
auxiliary_module.some_function()
```

auxiliary_module.py

```py
import logging

# create logger
module_logger = logging.getLogger(f'__main__.{__name__}')


def some_function():
    module_logger.info('received a call to "some_function"')
```

Now, from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714316/how-to-use-logging-getlogger-name-in-multiple-modules), I infer that `getLogger(__name__)` should not actually be used in EVERY module that uses logging but instead in the module where a logger is configured, which in this case would be main_module.py

e.g. In the auxiliary module, trying to get the custom logger through `getLogger(__name__)` will return the root logger, whereas `getLogger(f'__main__.{__name__}')` will return that custom logger.

To me, this formatting of `getLogger(f'__main__.{__name__}')` doesn't seem much easier to write than the explicit `getLogger('main_module.auxiliary_module')`. Furthermore, in the log files it logs `__main__.auxiliary_module` rather than `main_module.auxiliary_module`, losing a bit of accuracy.

Lastly, I previously stated that to my understanding, `getLogger(__name__)` should only be placed in the module where the logger is configured. However, configuration should be placed in a config file or dict anyways.

Thus, I don't seem to understand any reasonable usage of `getLogger(__name__)` and how it is, according to the docs, a best practice. Could someone explain this and maybe link a repo that uses loggers with proper organisation that I could refer to? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume this simple project:

```
project/
├── app.py
├── core
│   ├── engine.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── utils
    ├── db.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Where `app.py` is:

```
import logging
import sys

from utils import db
from core import engine

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stdout = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdout.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(name)s: %(message)s"))
logger.addHandler(stdout)


def run():
    db.start()
    engine.start()


run()
```

and `utils/db.py` and `core/engine.py` is:

```
from logging import getLogger

print(__name__)  # will print utils.db or core.engine
logger = getLogger(__name__)
print(id(logger))  # different object for each module; child of root though


def connect():
    logger.info("started")
```

If you run this using `python app.py`, you will see that it takes care of printing the **proper** namespaces for you.

```
utils.db: started
core.engine: started
```

**If your code is well organised, your module name itself is the best logger name available**. If you had to reinvent those names,  it usually means that you have a bad module structure (or some special,
non-standard use case). For most purposes though, this should work fine (hence part of stdlib).

That is all there is to it. Remember, you don't really set *handlers* for [libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library); that is left to the consumer.

Comment: Really appreciate the post! I may have miscommunicated my main issue. I understand how `getLogger(__name__)` can work if you are configuring the root logger as you are doing in app.py, `getLogger()`, since `getLogger(__name__)` in db.py and engine.py will return the root logger and provide the location of the module. However, I thought it was best practice to configure custom loggers, and so my main question was more so targeted at using `getLogger(__name__)` for custom loggers. Could you provide an example of using `getLogger(__name__)` with custom loggers if you wouldn't mind? Thanks again!!

Comment: `__name__` is variable in `getLogger(__name__)`; it returns a different object (check the `id`, it is not the same as the root logger). I have added some code to print this. I don't think custom logger is the best practice :-).

Comment: If you really want to use a custom logging convention, then I think you need to explicitly define names like you are doing. Also, if you are in a learning phase, skip the details ... over time you will get the bigger picture (This is from my experience :-)). I used to get bogged down with details like this; but with experience I understood the exact use case and why it works etc.