# How to use the same logger in different python modules?

Tags: python, logging

Here is what I have in the main code:

```
from mf import gameplay

....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create a file handler
    handler = logging.FileHandler('example.log')
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create a logging format
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(worker)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add the file handler to the logger
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    logger.info("Querying database for docs...", extra={'worker': 'id_1'})
```

and in a module `gameplay` I import in the main code I have

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")
logger.info("test module")
```

but still I do not get any log output from the logger in the module. I do not see the text "test module" in the logging file "example.log".

I looked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714316/how-to-use-logging-getlogger-name-in-multiple-modules), [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html), [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-logging-in-multiple-modules) and [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) and I think I followed what is described in all these articles but it is still not working for me. I am pretty sure I overlooked something totally simple.

What am I missing?

MacOS, python 3.9.6

Answer (score 0):

Logging it kind of tricky in Python.

Try:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I usually do this:

```
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf", disable_existing_loggers=False)
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

```
[loggers]
keys=root,app

[handlers]
keys=console_handler

[formatters]
keys=normal_formatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=console_handler

[logger_app]
level=INFO
handlers=console_handler
qualname=app
propagate=0

[handler_console_handler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=normal_formatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_normal_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Comment: Still does not seem to work. I "imported"(?) the logger in the module as `logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")` but the text does not make it into the logging file...

Comment: Ah wait you don't write to a file...

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* the problem was that I defined the logger *after* I imported the other module. To solve this problem:

**Define the logger at the very top of your main code before you import any of your modules!**

If that is correct, the example given [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules) must be incorrect!

In the main code I now have

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a file handler
handler = logging.FileHandler('gameplay.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a logging format and add that to the logger
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

import <other modules>
```

and in the other modules I have e.g.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")
logger.debug("Game module loaded")
```